# Android login to a site which has Session ID

Tags: android, session, sid

I am trying to login to an internal wireless with security. I can do HTTP POST requests, but it doesn't work for this login site. I suspect it has something to do with it giving the user a Session ID, as the login page URL is http://blahblah.com/login/Login.php?sid=(string of numbers and letters).

I have just been trying to POST data to http://blahblah.com/login/Login.php and that is unsuccessful.

So my question is: how do I obtain the SID in order to logon to the site with the correct URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to parse the response the server is giving you (assuming in fact you need a session ID, not design an oauth process). Most server session ID's are given in xml form. There is a native java XML parser but you can google that and figure out how youd like to handle that. you will probably need to append your session ID to your POST URL as well.